# How can I increase and decrease the quantity seperately?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm implementing a shopping cart increase and decrease function by pure JS. When I click the + or - button, if there is 2 items in the shopping cart, the 2 of them will increase or decrease at the same time.

here is my code

```
function loadCart() {
    let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    let cartTotalItem = document.querySelector('.cart__value');
    cartTotalItem.textContent = products.length;
    products.forEach(product => {
        let cartItem = document.createElement('tr');
        cartItem.innerHTML = `<td><img src="${product.imgSrc}" alt='product image'></td>
                  <td>${product.name}</td>
                  <td><span class='cart-price'>${product.price},000vnd</span></td>
                  <td>
                    <button data-action="remove" onclick='decrease()'>-</button>
                    <input name='product' class="product__quantity" type="number" min='1' max='100' value='${product.count}'>
                    <button data-action="add" onclick='increase()'>+</button>
                  </td>
                  <td><span class='cart-total-value'>${parseInt(product.price) * product.count},000vnd</span></td>
                  <td>
                    <button class="delete--item"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                  </td>`;
        tableBody.appendChild(cartItem);
    });
}

function increase() {
    let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        let inputValue = document.querySelector('.product__quantity').value;
        inputValue = products[i].count++;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
    tableBody.innerHTML = '';
    loadCart();
}

function decrease() {
    let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        let inputValue = document.querySelector('.product__quantity').value;
        inputValue = products[i].count--;
        if (products[i].count <= 0) {
            const itemIndex = products.findIndex(product => product.count === 0);
            products.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
    tableBody.innerHTML = '';
    loadCart();
}
```

Someone help me with this.

Comment: `increase(${product.name})`, `decrease(${product.name})` might be a good start

Comment: This `let inputValue = document.querySelector('.product__quantity').value;` will not work as expected. A) you should rely on JS variables, not HTML content B) this line always refers to the first matching element, regardless of `i` C) you're overwriting `inputValue` in the very next line, however this will in no way have any effect on the HTML

Comment: Don't you have an object representing the current state and content of the shopping cart? Hard to believe that you only have the product name in your localStorage and the amount only unbound in an input field.

Comment: @Jejun you are right!!! Silly me for not passing the product.name to the function

Comment: @ChrisG thank you sir for pointing out my mistakes. Glad to read your comment!

Comment: @Rob thank you Rob! I am fixing my code right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your for loop.
You loop through the products array and then you update the count of each product.

`inputValue = products[i].count++;`

You should only update the count of the product selected, you could do this by passing a product identifier to your increase and decrease functions.

There are other issues in the code but the above should answer your question;

Comment: Thank you sir. Indeed it's because I don't have a unique identifier for each products. Stupid me.

Comment: Glad I could help. Not a "sir" tho :)

Comment: I am sorry :( btw thank you for your help!